# Extracting an excel file path from another excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, path

I have a file called 'workbooks_to_process.xlsx' with a column that contains the following excel files' paths:

```
**files_paths_2_process**     (column header)
  c:/work/file01.xlsx
  c:/work/file02.xlsx
  c:/work/file03.xlsx
    ………………….
  c:/work/file0m.xlsx
```

**On the other hand in Python Pandas**

```
df_0 = pd.read_excel('workbooks_to_process.xlsx') # No issue
list_of_paths = df_0[files_paths_2_process].tolist() # No issue
```

## Following is what I want to do (in an iterative process)

```
itr = list_of_paths[3]  # or [0], [1], [n] etc

df_1 = pd.read_excel(itr)
```

Is there any method to accomplish the above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for iterating through all files in a folder and all sheets in those files . try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
file_list = [os.path.join(r,file) for r,d,f in os.walk("C:\\Users\\ref_folder\\") for file in f] 
for file in list(file_list):
    f = pd.ExcelFile(file)
    sheet_names = f.sheet_names
    for i in list(sheet_names):
        dataframe = pd.read_excel(f,i)
```

this dataframe will give you dataframe for every sheets, works for workbooks having 1 sheet too.

You can match the filename with your excel column filename and if it matches, read the df. I feel this is the most generalized way you can iterate through files in a folder and read as a df.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you anky! Still, it doesn't work for me. Could you please take a look to the below and advise on what I'm doing wrong?

 file_list = [os.path.join(r,file) for r,d,f in os.walk('C:/Users/JG/work/files_cargo.xlsx') for file in f]                                                     

 for file in list(file_list):
         f = pd.read_excel(file)
            sheet_names = f.sheet_names
        for i in list(sheet_names):
            dataframe = pd.read_excel(f,i)
        
    type(dataframe)

    NameError: name 'dataframe' is not defined

Comment: @JulioGomez : read excel doesnot have the feature of reading sheets, if you see my code, I have used the `ExcelFile` feature to read the file which can give you `f.sheet_names`

Comment: It took me a little  time to fully understand your code , but finally I could achieve what I required. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`for itr in range(len(list_of_paths)):
    df_1 = pd.read_excel(list_of_paths[itr])
    ...
    ...`